Laravel Filament Relationship Title Attribute
When displaying the form for a model and it's select relationship, I want to customize the title attribute it displays in the selection. Specifically, I want to have the user title come back as 'first_name last_name'.
This is standard:
public static function form(Form $form): Form
    {
        return $form
            ->schema([
                Select::make('user_id')
                    ->relationship('user', 'first_name')
                    ->required(),
                TextInput::make('name')
                    ->required()
                    ->maxLength(255),
            ]);
    }

and it returns something like this

but I want first and last name, not just first name.
I did see Laravel - Filament: get distinct values of a relationship column
which made me think I could do some kind of query, like
->relationship('user', 'first_name', function(Builder $query) {
                        $query->select('id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email');


but nothing seems to work because you still call the column in the 2nd argument to query...
I can do a query and where, and it will filter by the where clause... 
In Laravel nova, you can easily do this
https://nova.laravel.com/docs/resources/relationships.html#title-attributes-1
public static $title = 'name';

/**
 * Get the value that should be displayed to represent the resource.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function title()
{
    return $this->first_name . ' ' . $this->last_name;
}

However, in filament, it doesn't seem like this is possible. I did see
https://filamentphp.com/docs/3.x/panels/resources/relation-managers, but that seems to only work on the relation manager page.
Since this 2nd argument is suppose to be a column name, it was suggested to create a virtual column like this:
$table->string('full_name')->virtualAs('concat(first_name, \' \', last_name)');

Is this really the only way?

You can use the getOptionLabelFromRecordUsing() method to transform an option's Eloquent model into a label
->getOptionLabelFromRecordUsing(fn (Model $record) => "{$record->first_name} {$record->last_name}")

Docs: https://filamentphp.com/docs/3.x/forms/fields/select#customizing-the-relationship-option-labels

Thanks! Not sure how I missed that, but that is exactly what I was looking for!
